# Kendo Grid Specials Characters

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, character

I'm using a Kendo Grid to read JSON datas.
"contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"," is indicated but the specials characters as 'é', 'à', etc ... aren't encoded and appear like "%Ã" or something else. How to dispay them as "é", "à", etc... ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are sending the correct encoding for the data but ... what about the HTML page including the grid?

Try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` to the `head` section of you HTML.

Comment: I already put 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: How are you serving your data php/java/.net/...? Is it static or dynamic content? Is your editor / IDE saving the file as UTF-8? Works perfectly well for me!

Comment: It's a JSON data.
I'm using Visual Studio and I recup the JSON data thanks to an AJAX request...

Comment: Try sending manually introduced data: edit a text file with the content that you want to be displayed and change your AJAX for reading this file. If this works then it is a problem on the data in the server side that you say it is UTF-8 but actually is something else.